# Textbox property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am writing a .net program using C#. I would like to ask how could I let the user resize
the Textbox, so that he could enlarge or diminish the textbox

Comment: It pays to monitor your questions as this site is very active... doing this in ASP.Net is easy, I'll give you a hint (this comment textbox is resizable) and leave you to work it out.

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy to do in Winforms, it takes but a few lines of code.  Every window in Windows has the innate ability to be sizable by the user.  This is normally only done for a top-level window (a form) but it works just as well for any client window.

The key is to respond to the WM_NCHITTEST message.  Which is a message that Windows sends to a window when you click on it.  It essentially asks "what was hit?"  You can simply say "the corner was hit" and then Windows takes it from there.  It changes the cursor to indicate that the corner can be dragged.  And automatically resizes the window when the user moves the mouse.

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto a form and set its Multiline property to true.  Press F5 and drag the lower-right corner of the textbox to see it work.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class SizeableTextBox : TextBox {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        // Intercept WM_NCHITTEST
        if (m.Msg == 0x84 && this.Multiline) {
            // Find out where the cursor is located
            var pos = PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()));
            // Return HTBOTTOMRIGHT if in the lower-right corner
            if (pos.X >= this.Width - 12 && pos.Y >= this.Height - 12) m.Result = (IntPtr)17;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native property for textboxes that allow you to resize them manually. What you *can* do is set the `dock` or `anchor` property so that when the user resizes the form it will resize the textbox with it.